# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild') on React

Tags: reactjs

I get Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild'), and dont know why i am getting this error

**Here i click on Link and  go to Details**

```
  import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
  import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

  function ImageDetails() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((result) => setData(result));
    }, []);

    return (
      <div>
        {data.slice(0,3).map((item) => (
          <div key={item.id}>
            <Link to={`/image/${item.id}`}>
              <img src={item.url} alt={item.title} />
            </Link>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default ImageDetails;
```

**Details**

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import OpenSeadragonViewer from "./dragon";

const Details = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [imagePath, setImagePath] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/${id}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => setImagePath(result.url));
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {imagePath && <OpenSeadragonViewer imagePath={imagePath} />}
    </>
  );
};

export default Details;
```

**OpenSeadragonViewer**

```
import OpenSeadragon from "openseadragon";
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const OpenSeadragonViewer = ({ imagePath }) => {
  const viewerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const viewer = OpenSeadragon({
      id: viewerRef.current,
      prefixUrl: "openseadragon/images/",
      tileSources: {
        type: "image",
        url: imagePath,
      },
    });

    if (viewerRef.current) {
      viewerRef.current.appendChild(viewer.element);
    }

    return () => {
      viewer.destroy();
    };
  }, [imagePath]);

  return <div ref={viewerRef} style={{ height: "500px" }}></div>;
};

export default OpenSeadragonViewer;
```

**And here is an image of error**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4n5hn.jpg)

I tried to add a child element to the useEffect function, which is called after the parent element has fully loaded.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think adding `viewerRef.current` to `useEffect` dependency list might fix this issue.

Comment: hi, in OpenSeadragonViewer?

Comment: Yes in the `OpenSeadragonViewer` `useEffect` dependency list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have one issue with logic of this.

Your `useEffect` in `OpenSeadragonViewer` depends on `imagePath` but when we will go up the tree we can see that in fact there is no chance for this value to change.

You get this value in `Details` using this `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/${id}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => setImagePath(result.url));
  }, []);
```

You put empty dependency, that means that you call this only once, and you do not change this anywhere else.

So in this case, simple fix for this would be just to change dependencies in `OpenSeadragonViewer` to be also called only once, by providing empty array as dependency.

But let's say that you will add option to change it, and you need this dependency by image url.

In this case I would recommend to split `useEffect`. First with empty dependency array to be called only once where you initiate the `OpenSeadragon` So something like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const viewer = OpenSeadragon({
      id: viewerRef.current,
      prefixUrl: "openseadragon/images/",
      tileSources: {
        type: "image",
        url: imagePath,
      },
    });

    return () => {
      viewer.destroy();
    };
  }, []);
```

And second `useEffect`, with dependency by `imagePath`, where you set the new path.

Then you need to move viewer declaration outside the `useEffect` to have access to it in both `useEffect`s.

Also, probably you shouldn't do something like this:

```
id: viewerRef.current,
```

You're already using this Ref as reference to div, using it as ID of different object is not a good practice.